# I cannot get the standard deviation from this pipe operation

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I am currently able to collapse a group of rows into one to obtain the mean of multiple columns for each ID through the following pipe function:

```
  group_by(customerid) %>%
  select_at(1:70) %>% fmean
```

But I cannot figure out how to switch out the fmean to obtain the standard deviation instead of the mean. Does anyone know the operation that can be used here? I tried sd, std, etc.

Comment: Please make a reproducible question by providing sample data.

Comment: I don't know anything about `fmean`, but the `sd` standard deviation function expects you to give it a vector/column, not a whole data frame. Typically `dplyr` uses `summarize` for this, `...select_at(1:70) %>% summarize(across(everything(), sd))`. Have a look at the [Introduction to dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) for lots of examples.